# Opening an http/2 connection and POSTing form-data

Tags: node.js, http2

### Objective

The objective of this code is to connect to an API service over http2, then maintain that connection so I may be able to POST multipart form data to the API:

```
let options = {
    port: 443,
    hostname: 'avs-alexa-na.amazon.com',
    path: '/v20160207/directives',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('CREDS')).access_token,
    }
  }
  var request = require('http2').request(options)
  request.on('response', function(response) {
    console.log(response)
    if (response.statusCode == 403) {
       //handle invalid token
    } else {
      //now lets make a POST request with form-data
    }
    //response.on('end', finish);
  });
```

### The Issue

I looked over the HTTP module docs and I saw use cases in which when you associate the request with a variable, you could use `request.write()` to send data, but I'm not entirely sure thats the right way to go about sending form-data. then I looked over the `form-data` module with this example:

```
var request = http.request({
  method: 'post',
  host: 'example.org',
  path: '/upload',
  headers: form.getHeaders()
});

form.pipe(request);

request.on('response', function(res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```

But in this case, I want to send form-data *AFTER* Ive established a connection with the API service and while on the same connection, as the [API Docs](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/managing-an-http-2-connection#create) says

> " After establishing the downchannel stream, your client must
>   synchronize it’s components’ states with AVS. This requires making a
>   POST request to /{{API version}}/events on a new event stream on the
>   existing connection (Note: Do not open a new connection). This event
>   stream should be closed when your client receives a response
>   (directive). The following is an example SynchronizeState event: "

So If I were to create another variable for another http2 request to another path using POST method, wouldn't that be creating a new connection?

I've successfully made a GET request to the API endpoint of that service, now it's a matter of POSTing form-data (multipart, if that makes a difference) to a different path while on the same existing connection.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I'm dealing with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Node HTTP2 docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#client-side-example) it shows an example of how to do this.

The key takeaway is that you need to create a "client" object with `client = http2.connect(url)` before finally requesting the data with `client.request({ ':path': '/' })`. This way, the client connection can be preserved when you make different requests.